# Flutter - Print document silently without preview panel?

Tags: flutter, printing, background, preview

I've been using **printing** plugin to print documents. It is working fine as expected.

Is it possible to print files without showing the preview panel which actually comes from android print?

For example, when user clicks a button it should print the file automatically without any user interaction or intervention.

Is this feasible?

Thanks.
Hussain

Answer (score 2):

```
await Printing.directPrintPdf ( 
   printer: Printer(url: 'name of your device(printer name)' 
), 
  onLayout: (format) => _generatePdf(format, title));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call what the preview calls; for example:

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
  onLayout: (format) => _generatePrint()
  name: 'tst.pdf',
  format: PdfPageFormat.roll80,
);
```